# Using arrays.xml in Android Manifest for intent-filters

Tags: android, arrays, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have a collection of 3rd party intents (various music players) stored in arrays.xml under ressources. Now I'd like to make use of them in the Android Manifest. I'm explicitly asking to this statically. I know that I could also do this in code but that would defeat the purpose of the app.

Anyway, since I'm afraid I know the answer: might there be a different way to maintain some sort of list that will be referenced from the Manifest?

Thanks in advance,
  steff

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, they are static, can't do that.

> An intent filter is an instance of the IntentFilter class. However,
>   since the Android system must know about the capabilities of a
>   component before it can launch that component, intent filters are
>   generally not set up in Java code, but in the application's manifest
>   file (AndroidManifest.xml) as elements.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs

Comment: Yes, I was expecting such a thing. Thank you. Any clever workaround?

Comment: Some kind of generalized dummy intent that reads information out of the bundle and makes an intelligent decision about which third party one to use.